# Send uint over TCP to server c#

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm trying to send an uint-Array to a Server. But i don't know how to realise it.
The `uint[]` looks like this:

```
[0,0,0,0, 255,255,255, 255,255,255]
```

I'am working with the `stream.Write` methode but this methode is only working with a `byte[]` how can i convert a `uint8[]` to a `byte[]` or is there any chance to send a `uint8[]` over tcp? The problem is i can't access the source code on the server nor change it.

**EDIT:** 
This is what i'm typing to the Chrome Console and it's working:

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:7890")
```

to open the websocket connection and the rest:
[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: uint8 is basically just a Byte, so the values are the same, so just use byte and send that to the server.

Comment: tried it but I don't get a response. 
For example, when i'am opening a websocket connection via Console in Chrome and sending those packages i'am getting a response from my FadeCandy Controller. But when i'am sending the same packages via the stream.Write, i don't get any response.

Comment: When its a byte array, do you know if it needs to be send as big endian or little endian. you can try reverse the array to see if that works.

Comment: Thanks but with this, i'am still getting no response, I added a screenshot in my first post, this is what i'am doing in the console. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Thats a websocket, you should use a websocket library to help you then, i thought this was a TCP client socket.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30524243/1805974 here is a detailed example of using WebSocket, atleast this should get you connected, then you can figure out sending the data.

Comment: Thanks, added it, but still no response. 
But my WebSocketSharp don't have a OnMessage() method. I've installed WebSocketSharp over NuGet.

Comment: It should be an event, so on the websocket it should be ws.OnMessage += (sender,e) => { //your code; }

Comment: plenty of examples here: https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp however the question have not gone quite off-topic

Comment: Thanks, it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert the array.
Something like:
var byteArray = uintArray.Select(item=>(Byte)item).ToArray();